# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value in @nestjs/jwt

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I can not get a token.I am using `import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';`.The package version is `"@nestjs/jwt": "^9.0.0"`.The  this.jwtService.sign(payload) function takes only one parameter. It shows error that I have been giving below.

```
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107:20)    at JwtService.sign (D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\node_modules\@nestjs\jwt\dist\jwt.service.js:28:20)      
    at AuthService.login (D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\src\auth\auth.service.ts:28:35)
    at AppController.login (D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\src\app.controller.ts:16:35)
    at D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29        
    at D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28        
    at D:\nextjs-projects\shopping-app\server_v2\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

My Code:
1.AuthModule code is given bellow:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'ndUdggLVxTccGBJmr1BoFvAQnSEt+Osx5pgdGTOL9XwajAn4fe40Q41NbBTa9wNekjKuTLdhWBJQhi71JShvi7rFoayh3QIuEA3e4Eq8mU7lwArngzFWdSiIJgMplTLboFOeR7q8pv7MoDcl2dBmuZI4NQ5GglznC8Ebl20Sa41cg4EDkuppblXa+bqvZeSQRg0d/AL9f8NIBC3N6sEyc1nM0MWeWc1CxKuljTVQm1g2RVLG1cSNU/a5vpmy/9UwYiDiIr2aCbD60EWkQMR2vDvW/0LsVun72xEqUTdY5UuczofpmhtCxm+yw9R7iFsNcNuJAyAQN0T9OtMyt9wzPA==',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

2.AuthService code is given bellow:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async login(user: any) {
    const payload = {
      name: user.email,
      sub: user.phone,
    };
    const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload);
    return {
      accessToken: token,
    };
  }
}
```

3.AppModule code is given bellow:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb+srv://${dbConstant.username}:${dbConstant.password}@cluster0.34saife.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, AuthService, JwtService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

4.AppController code is given bellow:

```
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req: any) {
    return await this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is jwtService.sign? Does it take a key parameter? To sign a JWT you need a ley.

Comment: please provide `jwtService.sign` code. That is the place where the error is happening.

Comment: Can you show your `AuthModule`, `AuthService`'s `constructor`, `AppModule`, and `AppController`?

Comment: I have modified the post

Comment: I have caught the problem. secret key does not pass through register.JwtModule.register({ secret: 'hskshgksgg', signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' }, }),

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **JwtSignOptions** as second parameter

```
async login(user: any) {
        const payload = {
          name: user.email,
          sub: user.phone,
        };
        const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload,{secret: "youSecretKey" });
        return {
          accessToken: token,
        };
}
```

Comment: It takes only one main parameter and the secret is given on registry time

Comment: I have caught the problem. secret key does not pass through register.JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'hskshgksgg',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
    }),

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use the same `AuthService` and `JwtService` from the `AuthModule` where you originally configure the `JwtModule`, you need to remove the `AuthService` and `JwtService` from the `AppModule`'s `providers` and only have the `AuthModule` in the `AppModule`'s `imports`. This will ensure that only one `AuthService` instance is created and used (the one in the `AuthModule`'s `providers` and `exports`).

The reason for your error is that you declare that you need a new `JwtService` via adding it to the `AppModule`'s `providers`, and the dependencies of `JwtService`, the options it uses, are optional, so there's no error on startup.

---

##### TL;DR: make your `AppModule` look like this

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb+srv://${dbConstant.username}:${dbConstant.password}@cluster0.34saife.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The problem is solved. thanks a lot, comrade. I have been searching solution to this problem for 2 days.

Comment: I've done as you said but still have the same problem.

Comment: @MaHdi without context of what your code looks like, there's not much I'll be able to do